# Binding a click on the canvas excluding the node, edge Cytoscape JS elements, to an action

Tags: cytoscape.js

How to bind a click event on the canvas, excluding the node, edge Cytoscape Elements to a function?

Example: I want to bind a click on the whitespace region - [here](http://pramttl.github.io/), to an event
The whitespace region is any space on the canvas excluding the space occupied by nodes and edges.

Answer (score 7):

Documentation http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.on says :

```
cy.on('tap', function(event){
  // target holds a reference to the originator
  // of the event (core or element)
  var evtTarget = event.target;

  if( evtTarget === cy ){
    console.log('tap on background');
  } else {
    console.log('tap on some element');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind to the core, and check the event target is not a graph element.